# Generating bell-shaped / optimum data which is NOT a density

Tags: r

I am willing to generate data in order to illustrate the ecological niche overlap due to individual variability.
To do so, I used the dnorm function. It works well, but of course it is a density and therefore is not accurate for niche representation, which is the performance in reaction to an environmental axis. Therefore, I should be able to change the variance WITHOUT to reduce the maximum performance, which is impossible when using densities (the area must remain constant).
Does anyone have an idea to generate some bell-shaped data, or optimum curve ? I use R but I think the same principle could be applied to any language - I just need to have the right data !
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution using the Kaiser-window function :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(signal)

x = seq(0, 10, 0.1)
Data <- data.frame(x1=x,
                   x2=x+1,#shifts the curve
                   y1=signal::kaiser(101, 100),
                   y2=signal::kaiser(101, 100),
                   y3=signal::kaiser(101, 50),
                   y4=signal::kaiser(101, 10))

A <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=Data,  ggplot2::aes(x=x1, y=y1))+
  ggplot2::geom_area(aes(fill="Species 1", colour="Species 1"), alpha = 0.7)+
  ggplot2::geom_area(data=Data,  ggplot2::aes(x=x2, y=y2, fill="Species 2", colour="Species 2"), alpha=0.7)+
  ggplot2::xlab("Environmental axis (e.g. light)")+
  ggplot2::ylab("Performance")+
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkturquoise", "darkmagenta"), name=element_blank())+
  ggplot2::scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkturquoise", "darkmagenta"), name=element_blank())+
  ggplot2::theme(plot.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
               panel.grid.major = ggplot2::element_blank(),
               panel.grid.minor = ggplot2::element_blank(),
               panel.border = ggplot2::element_blank(),
               legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 20),
               legend.position="none",
               axis.title=element_blank(),
               axis.text=element_blank(),
               axis.ticks=element_blank())

B <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=Data,  ggplot2::aes(x=x1, y=y3))+
  ggplot2::geom_area(aes(fill="Species 1", colour="Species 1"), alpha = 0.7)+
  ggplot2::geom_area(data=Data,  ggplot2::aes(x=x2, y=y4, fill="Species 2", colour="Species 2"), alpha=0.7)+
  ggplot2::xlab("Environmental axis (e.g. light)")+
  ggplot2::ylab("Performance")+
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkturquoise", "darkmagenta"), name=element_blank())+
  ggplot2::scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkturquoise", "darkmagenta"), name=element_blank())+
  ggplot2::theme(plot.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.major = ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 panel.grid.minor = ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 panel.border = ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 20),
                 axis.title=element_blank(),
                 axis.text=element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks=element_blank())

figure <- ggpubr::ggarrange(A, B, ncol = 2, labels = c("A", "B"), common.legend=TRUE, legend="right")
annotate_figure(figure,
                bottom = text_grob("Environmental axis (e.g. light)", size = 20, x=0.4),
                left = text_grob("Performance", rot = 90, size = 20))
```

[image: niche_overlap]